# Curl request different from browser

Tags: api, http, curl

Im trying to access an API from ESA. details [here](https://scihub.esa.int/twiki/do/view/SciHubUserGuide/5APIsAndBatchScripting) 
when using curl,

```
curl -svgu <user>:<password> "https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products?$filter=year(IngestionDate) eq 2015 and month(IngestionDate) eq 10 and day(IngestionDate) eq 10"
```

The responde comes with wrong dates (2014)

Using the same link, on chrome, yields the expected result (files with the date passed)

```
https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products?$filter=year(IngestionDate) eq 2015 and month(IngestionDate) eq 10 and day(IngestionDate) eq 10
```

I tried to remove spaces and use

```
`"https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products?$filter=year(IngestionDate)%20eq%202015%20and%20month(IngestionDate)%20eq%2010%20and%20day(IngestionDate)%20eq%2010"`
```

on curl.

Any suggestions or ideas? You can use those links to try.

EDIT:
Per suggestion of [Pafjo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25174/pafjo), 
curl -G -gu  : "https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products" --data-urlencode '$filter=year(IngestionDate) eq '"$YEAR and month(IngestionDate) eq $MONTH and day(IngestionDate) eq $DAY"  this is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl does not url encode your url so you need to tell it what part that should be url-encoded.

Try this and see if you the correct response:

```
curl -G -svgu  <user>:<password> "https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products" --data-urlencode '$filter=year(IngestionDate) eq 2015 and month(IngestionDate) eq 10 and day(IngestionDate) eq 10'
```

The reason that your second curl command failed is that you have $filter inside double quotes. So when you do the request the shell will replace your variables with values. This is fixed by using single quotes or escaping the dollar sign.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Just one last question, I'm using the dates with variables, how should I pass then to the string? I'm trying like this --data-urlencode '$filter=year(IngestionDate) eq '"$YEAR"' and month(IngestionDate) eq '"$MONTH"' and day(IngestionDate) eq '"$DAY"

Comment: Ok. Try to use double quoutes but escape the first dollar sign:  curl -G -svgu user:password "https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products" --data-urlencode "\$filter=year(IngestionDate) eq $year and month(IngestionDate) eq 10 and day(IngestionDate) eq 10"

Comment: Doesn't work. Im thinking of constructing a string and append it to the '$filter=year(IngestionDate)'

Comment: manage to work it out with --data-urlencode '$filter=year(IngestionDate) eq '"$YEAR and month(IngestionDate) eq $MONTH and day(IngestionDate) eq $DAY"

Answer (score 0):

1. Curl arguments can be susceptible to interpretation from the shell you are using. You may need to escape regex characters, in this case ( and ).
2. Spaces are not allowed in URL's. You should probably replace them with %20.

Comment: can you produce no 1 for me pls?

Comment: I tried using uyour suggestions but I have the same problem "Products?$filter=year\(\IngestionDate\)\%20eq%202015"

Comment: slashes come before the parenthesis:
`\(IngestionDate\)`

Comment: I tried before, after and before and after. My comment has before and after but it is not shown (dunno why)